# Open and edit a .wav file in Photoshop (view wavelength)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, screenshot, visualization

Trying to find a way (better and higher quality of a screenshot) to open a .wav file in Photoshop and view and edit the wavelength file.

Initially, I used Adobe Audition and Onde ScreenCapture. The file size saved was only a 15kb .png file. Very poor quality. It seems screenshots are the way to go, but I was hoping to find something (program, plug-in, etc.) to create higher resolution programs. They exist, just can't find it.

Does anyone know of any solutions I might look into to get higher quality wave form visualizations that could be used in print designs?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to edit the actual wave lengths or you want to edit an IMAGE of the wavelengths?

Comment: Trying to edit the image of a wavelength. I can save a screenshot, but these are all pretty low quality images.

Comment: A simple search brought me to this page: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/supported-file-formats-photoshop-cs6.html

Furthermore, visualizing wavelengths from an audio file isn't something that Photoshop knows how to do. You're going to need a specific program to read and convert that audio data into something visual, which can then be edited in Ps or Ai.

Comment: How did you try to get the screenshot initially? Where were you viewing the .wav file? And what size resolution are you working on in Photoshop?

Comment: Initially, I used Adobe Audition and Onde ScreenCapture. The file size saved was only a 15kb .png file. Very poor quality. It seems screenshots are the way to go, but I was hoping to find something (program, plug-in, etc.) to create higher resolution programs. They exist, just can't find it.

Comment: @Ryan - Here are larger scale companies that do this type of work. So, I know it is possible. http://www.bespokenart.com/index.html

Comment: For companies like that they probably roll their own software specifically for it. You asked with the Photoshop tag so that's what I tried to provide you. For better results you might want to look into OpenFrameworks or Processing for opensource solutions. Was just one of many posts on the topic you might look into: http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/sound-waveform-display/2632/6

Answer (score 1):

This will be dependent on the size and quality of your monitor, because it does use a screenshot, but here's what I did:

1. First opened the .WAV file I wanted to capture in Adobe Audition which if you're using Photoshop you might have through your CC Subscription.
2. Then went into **Edit → Preferences → Appearance** and changed the Waveform Foreground Color to be a super saturated red (255, 0, 0). That gets me something like this:

[image: Audition 1]

3. Now with our high contrast image I'm just going to reduce all of the other panels as much as possible so the Waveform can take up the majority of my monitor.
4. Print Screen
5. Open in Photoshop, select Crop the area with the waveform from the remaining UI.
6. Select Color Range and you're done. Not 300 ppi or anything but pretty good considering what you're after:

[image: Audition Wave in Photoshop]

I can now easily manipulate it however I want.

Comment: I'll have to try this. Great response. I know someone has a program or plug-in dealing with .wav files as companies like this exist. http://www.bespokenart.com/index.html